# how to insert an image into a listview?

Tags: android, image, listview, visible, invisible

I would like to insert a small image to the right of each item in a listview 
basically my app should do so as soon as the user clicks on an item in the list view, the image becomes visible, otherwise it must remain invisible.

below is my activity with its XML

Activity

```
public class EpisodiActivity extends Activity {

public class ViewModel {
    private String url;
    private String name;

    public ViewModel(String url, String name) {
        this.url = url;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return this.url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //creazione fullscreen activity
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.episodi_activity);

    String[] episodi = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("Product");
    String[] urls = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("urls");

    ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);


    // And in this loop we create the ViewModel instances from 
    // the name and url and add them all to a List
    List<ViewModel> models = new ArrayList<ViewModel>();
    for (int i = 0; i < episodi.length; i++) {
        String name = episodi[i];
        String url = "No value";
        if (i < urls.length) {
            url = urls[i];
        }
        ViewModel model = new ViewModel(url, name);
        models.add(model);
    }


    // Here we create the ArrayAdapter and assign it to the ListView
    // We pass the List of ViewModel instances into the ArrayAdapter
    final ArrayAdapter<ViewModel> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ViewModel>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, models);

    mylist.setAdapter(adapter);


    mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {

            // Here we get the ViewModel at the given position
            ViewModel model = (ViewModel) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);

            // And the url from the ViewModel
            String url = model.getUrl();

            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
        }
    });
}
```

XML

```
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/pubblicita"
    android:cacheColorHint="#ffd700"
    android:background="@drawable/sfondobottone" />
```

Comment: see my answer i hope it helps you

Answer (score 4):

I think you want this kind of output in listview

**text with image in listview**

[image]

You can use custom listview . Make a class which extends BaseAdapter class

here is the exmaple that i am using

**Your BaseAdapter**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class FrontListBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
     private static ArrayList<FrontDetails> itemDetailsrrayList;

     private LayoutInflater l_Inflater;

     public FrontListBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FrontDetails> results) {
      itemDetailsrrayList = results;
      l_Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
     }

     public int getCount() {
      return itemDetailsrrayList.size();
     }

     public Object getItem(int position) {
      return itemDetailsrrayList.get(position);
     }

     public long getItemId(int position) {
      return position;
     }

      // get the views in frontview xml file where you have
      // define multiple views that will appear in listview each row
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      ViewHolder holder;
      if (convertView == null) {
       convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.frontview, null);
       holder = new ViewHolder();
       holder.Image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.adminpic1);
       holder.MsgType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.msgtype1);

       convertView.setTag(holder);
      } else {
       holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
      }


      holder.Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.mainlogo); // you can set your setter here
      holder.MsgType.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getMsgType());

      return convertView;
     }

     // holder view for views
     static class ViewHolder {
      ImageView Image;
      TextView MsgType;
     }
    }
```

your FrontDetails class where you will make getters and setters and this class will be used in final ArrayList resultse = new ArrayList();

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class FrontDetails {

    public int getImage() {
    return image;
    }
    public void setImage(int imageN) {
    this.image = imageN;
    }


    public String getMsgType() {
    return MsgType;
    }
    public void setMsgType(String text) {
    this.MsgType = text;
    }



    private int image;
    private String MsgType;

    }
```

your frontview.XML where you put your multiple views that will be in each row or your layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/adminpic1"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/msgtype1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:textSize="1sp"
                android:text="MsgType" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and your listview in xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sync"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sync" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

now in your main activity

```
    final ArrayList<FrontDetails> resultse = new ArrayList<FrontDetails>();
FrontListBaseAdapter asdf = new FrontListBaseAdapter(context, resultse);
                lv1.setAdapter(new FrontListBaseAdapter(Front.this, resultse));


 lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int position, long arg3) {

                    Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    FrontDetails obj_itemDetails = (FrontDetails)o;
                    Toast.makeText(context, "You have chosen " + ' ' + obj_itemDetails.getMsgType(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
        });
```

**EDIT:
From here i learned Custom Listview its a simple exmaple with image**

http://www.javasrilankansupport.com/2012/05/android-listview-example-with-image-and.html

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/10/android-listview-example-with-image-and.html

Answer (score 1):

Use custom listview with BaseAdapter

Your Adapter

```
public class CustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
List<RowItem> rowItems;

public CustomBaseAdapter(Context context, List<RowItem> items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rowItems = items;
}

/*private view holder class*/
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtDesc;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
        context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    RowItem rowItem = (RowItem) getItem(position);

    holder.txtDesc.setText(rowItem.getDesc());
    holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {    
    return rowItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return rowItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
}
```

}

Your list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:textColor="#CC0033"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/desc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textColor="#3399FF"
    android:textSize="14dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Your Single Row item class

```
public class RowItem {
private int imageId;
private String title;
private String desc;

public RowItem(int imageId, String title, String desc) {
    this.imageId = imageId;
    this.title = title;
    this.desc = desc;
}
public int getImageId() {
    return imageId;
}
public void setImageId(int imageId) {
    this.imageId = imageId;
}
public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}
public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return title + "\n" + desc;
}  
}
```

List view implementation

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    CustomBaseAdapter adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(this, rowItems);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give some tips ,but unfortunately couldn't help you by example..

First of all create one custom adapter(extends BaseAdapter) followed by one custom layout..
Here the custom layout contains the textview and one image view(by default invisible) at the right.

Just customize your list view with your adapter and put text inside TextView through get view()..

At last in your listItemClickListener  make the image visible by its position.

Answer (score -2):

You can set here on xml like this

```
android:visibility="visible"
```

or

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

or

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Java program:

```
ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.custom);
```

set your ImageView like this

```
imgView .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


imgView .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


imgView .setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Difference between INVISIBLE and GONE.

`INVISIBLE` - The widget will be invisible but space for the widget will be show.

`GONE` - Both space and widget is invisible.

Now you can hook your `setOnItemClickListener()`

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
 @Override 
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
 { 
    imgView .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }
});
```

Comment: i dont understand why there is a vote-down, the answer clearly explains how to make a imageview `Invisible` and on listview item click make that imageview `Visible`.